# Get max from unwound arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents where I want to find the maximum values of each of the ratios of every possible pair of fields in the `data` object. For example:

Documents:

```
[
    { data: { a: 1, b: 5, c: 2 } },
    { data: { a: 4, b: 1, c: 1 } },
    { data: { a: 2, b: 4, c: 3 } }
]
```

Desired output:

```
{
    a: { a: 1, b: 4, c: 4   },
    b: { a: 5, b: 1, c: 2.5 },
    c: { a: 2, b: 1, c: 1   }
}
```

So the output `a.b` is the largest of the a:b ratios `1/5`, `4/1`, and `2/4`.

So I figure I first use `$objectToArray` to convert `data`, then `$unwind` on the result, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to group everything together. The number of documents I have won't be too large, but the number of keys in `data` can be in the low thousands, so I'm not sure how well Mongo will be able to handle doing a bunch of `$lookup`'s and comparing the values like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { data: { $objectToArray: "$data" } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            pairs: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $multiply: [ { $size: "$data" }, { $size: "$data" } ] } ] },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                leftIndex: { $floor: { $divide: [ "$$index", { $size: "$data" } ] } },
                                rightIndex: { $mod: [ "$$index", { $size: "$data" } ] }
                            },
                            in: {
                                l: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", "$$leftIndex" ] },
                                r: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", "$$rightIndex" ] }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$pairs" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { l: "$pairs.l.k", r: "$pairs.r.k" },
            value: { $max: { $divide: [ "$pairs.l.v", "$pairs.r.v" ]  } }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "_id.l": 1, "_id.r": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.l",
            values: { $push: { k: "$_id.r", v: "$value"  } }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { values: { $arrayToObject: "$values" } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            root: [ { k: "$_id", v: "$values" } ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "root.k": 1 }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: "$root"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you need [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to transform between arrays and objects. Basically the point is that for each object you need to generate `nxn` pairs (`3x3=9` in this case). You can perform such iteration using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) operator. Then using [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/index.html) and [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) with [$floor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/index.html) you can get index pairs like `(0,0)...(2,2)`. Then you just need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) to get max values for each pair type (like `a` with `b` and so on). To get final shape you also need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html).

Outputs:

```
{ "a" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 4, "c" : 4 } }
{ "b" : { "a" : 5, "b" : 1, "c" : 2.5 } }
{ "c" : { "a" : 2, "b" : 1, "c" : 1 } }
```